# AWS lambda Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: bus error Runtime.ExitError intermittently

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sharp

Lambda function intermittently stopped with throw error `Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: bus error Runtime.ExitError`

Function is compresses and processes images using sharp

The error does not come out even with the same image, but I want to know the cause of this error

```
2023-04-14T09:37:16.284Z    Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: bus error Runtime.ExitError
2023-04-14T09:37:16.284Z    END 
2023-04-14T09:37:16.284Z    REPORT Duration: 566.11 ms Billed Duration: 567 ms Memory Size: 4096 MB Max Memory Used: 190 MB
```

```yaml
runtime: nodejs16.x
memorySize: 4096
package:
  ioredis : 4.19.4
  firebase-admin: 9.4.0
  axios: 0.21.4
  sharp : 0.30.7
```

I use sharp with HEIC support https://github.com/zoellner/sharp-heic-lambda-layer

```yaml
//lambda layer info
WEBP_VERSION: 1.2.4
LIBDE265_VERSION: 1.0.8
LIBHEIF_VERSION: 1.12.0
VIPS_VERSION: 8.12.2
SHARP_VERSION: 0.30.7
```

```json
// Sharp image.metadata();
{
  format: 'jpeg',
  size: 1724008,
  width: 4032,
  height: 3024,
  space: 'srgb',
  channels: 3,
  depth: 'uchar',
  density: 72,
  chromaSubsampling: '4:2:0',
  isProgressive: false,
  hasProfile: false,
  hasAlpha: false
}
```

I tried the same lambda function with the same image, but it worked without any errors